# Kernel Density estimation of a bi-dimensional grid

Tags: c++, statistics

I have a 2D grid of integers value that represents the presence, or the absence of certain events in a given location of the grid: if the value of the cell is 0 there are no events, 1 means one event, and so on.

I need to compute the corresponding grid of density values by using the [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).

How can I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com or http://math.stackexchange.com